# Django: Accessing ImageField in clean()/save() at creation time and updates

Tags: python, django

I have a model in Django which has a lot of computed fields, it looks like this:

```
class Media(models.Model):
    titel = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    datei = models.ImageField(upload_to='usermedia/%Y/')

    # automatically calculated fields
    width = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False)
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False)
    imagetype = models.CharField(editable=False, max_length=32)
    thumbnail_b64 = models.CharField(
        editable=False, max_length=4096)

    def clean(self):
        self.width = self.datei.width
        self.height = self.datei.height

        self.imagetype = magic.from_buffer(self.datei.read(), mime=True)

        buffer = BytesIO()
        img = Image.open(self.datei)

        img.thumbnail((32, 32))
        img.save(buffer, format="PNG")

        self.thumbnail_b64 = base64.b64encode(
            buffer.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
```

Everything is good at a first glance - the model does what is meant to, at least at adding new Instances. But as soon as I try to **update** one instance, then Django raises an error:

> Exception Type:    ValueError
>   Exception Value: read of closed file

The problem seems to be `self.imagetype = magic.from_buffer(self.datei.read(), mime=True)`. I think `self.datei` is no longer in the memory, right?

I therefore changed the `from_buffer` thingy from both parts into:

```
self.imagetype = magic.from_file(self.datei.path, mime=True)
...
img = Image.open(self.datei.path)
```

Now I can finally update my model instances, but now, whenever I add new instances, I am getting a

> `FileNotFoundError`

**How would a solution look like that works for both, adding new entries and updating old ones?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to distinuish between an UPDATE and and INSERT seems to be:

```
    if(self.pk):
        # this is an update
        self.imagetype = magic.from_file(self.datei.path, mime=True)
        img = Image.open(self.datei.path)
    else:
        # this is a new record
        self.imagetype = magic.from_buffer(self.datei.read(), mime=True)
        img = Image.open(self.datei)
```

See [this](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.x/ref/models/instances.html#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert) docs chapter, I don't like the solution but at least it works